# Execute "ionic serve". Who encountered such a issue

Tags: ionic3

**strong text**

```
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser - 
Ctrl+C to cancel
[16:16:02]  watch started ... 
[16:16:02]  build dev started ... 
[16:16:02]  clean started ... 
[16:16:02]  clean finished in 40 ms 
[16:16:02]  copy started ... 
[16:16:02]  deeplinks started ... 
[16:16:02]  deeplinks finished in 200 ms 
[16:16:02]  transpile started ... 
[16:16:05]  transpile finished in 3.23 s 
[16:16:05]  preprocess started ... 
[16:16:05]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[16:16:05]  webpack started ... 
[16:16:05]  copy finished in 3.74 s 
[16:16:14]  webpack finished in 8.72 s 
[16:16:14]  sass started ... 
[16:16:15]  sass finished in 876 ms 
[16:16:15]  postprocess started ... 
[16:16:15]  postprocess finished in 20 ms 
[16:16:15]  lint started ... 
[16:16:15]  build dev finished in 13.43 s 
[16:16:15]  watch ready in 13.68 s 
[16:16:15]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/ 

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.2.25:8100
     DevApp: ijb-App@8100 on 6MBJYQ77APC23S4
```

Implementation of `ionic serve`, the browser can not be accessed, but there is no continuous opening of the console command line

Console has an error message:

```
 GET http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js net::ERR_ABORTED(index):52 
 GET http://localhost:8100/build/main.js net::ERR_ABORTEDion-dev.js?v=3.1.5:120 
 Dev server logger closed
 12livereload.js?snipver=1:74 WebSocket connection to 
 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: 
 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :  `ionic serve -w chrome --lab`

This defines chrome as the browser to use.
Maybe this helps, There is an issue in [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-dont-launch-browser/79621)

Comment: yes，i do that.The console has an error message: Look at the modified question above

Comment: I think it has something to do with the vendor.js file.
Please Check this : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/vendor-js-error-on-android/99647